# how can i select only the first two rows for every level (0) in my multiindex pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

say i have a df, and i group by two columns. i then want to only take the first two rows for my grouped by object. i.e.

```
grouped_data = df.groupby(['company','person']).first()
```

how do i then select the first two rows for each of these. e.g. for company = asda there are 8 rows i,e, 9 people under this company but i only want the first two rows. how can i do this using the dataframe above? note i have used first because after grouping by i want to retain the column by column information without aggregation.

Comment: `groupby().head(2)`?

Comment: df.groupby(['company','person']).head(2) does not give you first two rows..

Answer (score 2):

If you want frist two rows for each companies you can do :

```
df.groupby('company').head(2)
```